# Knots and Embedding

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

> What is the different between a smooth embedding and a homeomorphism?

I read a little about knots and I do not understand how a knot can be an embedding of the unit circle but not homeomorphic to it?

Comment: Do you know the definition of an embedding? Also, all knots are homeomorphic; you want to consider smooth isotopy or ambient isotopy or the like, which are stronger notions than homeomorphism

Comment: An embedding is a continuous function which is a homeomorphism to its image.